# Pre-fill a cell with today's date

Tags: google-sheets, date

I would like a certain cell of mine to display today's date when I starts a new row.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert the current date into a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47071/how-to-insert-the-current-date-into-a-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [@Jacob Jan Tuinstra](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69458/60716), TODAY updates automatically (so does NOW) and as I don't see the value of an entire column within which each cell always shows the current date, I interpret the requirement to be for a non-volatile solution. Hence suggest:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`;`

in the cell starting a new row. For such cells to be populated with the same result automatically would require a script with an OnEdit trigger.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the =NOW() function inside that cell;

http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=82712&version=static#section_Date

Answer (score 3):

For todays date, you can use the following formula.

### Formula

```
=TODAY()
```

### Explained

The `TODAY()` formula provides the current date with no time component. It's better to use that, than to use the `NOW()` formula. This will update on every edit made to the sheet, see reference.

### Note

Please realize that the value returned by the `TODAY()` formula isn't permanent.

### Reference

1. [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?rd=1)
2. [NOW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?rd=1)