# How to add row to Google Sheet daily with two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, appsheet

I would like to add a row every day at midnight to my Google Sheet containing two columns: 1st the current date, 2nd the cell value from another sheet (portfolio value).
I.e.: I want to make a graph to see the development of my stock portfolio value over time.
I read somewhere that you could do it with the script editor, but couldn't find a good enough example for me to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to insert a new row once a day (at midnight), and insert a timestamp in column A, and the value of another cell in Column B.

It would be unusual to find a exact precedent for this scenario, but identifying the various elements simplifies the task.

**1 - every day at midnight**

This is done by adding a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to the script. "Day Timer", and the time of day "Midnight to 1am".

**2 - add a new row**

There is a specific method for this: `appendRow(rowContents)` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).

The advantage of this method is that it not only that it adda the new row, but updates the data at the same time.

**3 - Column A = the current date**

[How to insert the current date into a Google Spreadsheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122697/196152) - does what is says on the tin.

**4 - Column B = the cell value from another sheet (portfolio value)**

A couple of things:

- `getSheetByName(name)`: since the input and the output are on different sheets, you need to declare the location of each.
- `getRange()`: declare the cell where the valuation can be found
- `getValue()`: get the value of the cell containing the valuation.

---

```
function dailyvaluation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // declare the source and target sheets
  var sheetnamePortfolio = "Portfolio"; // sheet containing the valuation
  var sheetnameDailyvalue = "DailyValue"// sheet to update daily
  var portfolio = ss.getSheetByName(sheetnamePortfolio);
  var daily = ss.getSheetByName(sheetnameDailyvalue);
  
  // declare the new date
  var newdate = new Date();
  // get the valuation
  // assume cell A1 of sheet="Portfolio"
  var value = portfolio.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the date is "+newdate+", and the value is "+value)
  
  // append the new row with the values
  daily.appendRow([newdate, value]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer! I managed to get it done with your suggestion! Merry Christmas!